# Why when I click on the superscripts of any footnote, it takes me to the first page of the document instead of the footnote?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

I am inserting some footnotes in my R Markdown document using the following syntax:

`^[This data is published on [website.](https://www.who.int)]`

Is there a way to make the references take me to the right place and not the first page of the document?

Comment: You mean the first page of the website?

Comment: I meant the first page on the pdf document